# How to write a recursive coroutines in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I would like to write a faster File Searcher in kotlin to find all text files under my home folder.

Here is my code with sequence search

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

var count: AtomicLong = AtomicLong(0)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(System.getProperty("user.home"))

  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  findTxtFile(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/git", ".txt")

  println("took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))

  println(count.get())
}


fun findTxtFile(path: String, extension: String) {
  File(path).listFiles().forEach {
    if (it.isDirectory) {
      findTxtFile(it.absolutePath, extension)
    } else if (it.name.endsWith(extension)) {
      count.getAndIncrement()
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote a program following, however when you have a lot of file, it throw NullPointerException, how could it possible throw null pointer Exception?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CommonPool
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking
import java.io.File

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var filePath = System.getProperty("user.home")
    var deferred = File(filePath).listFiles().map { path ->
        async(CommonPool) {
            findTxtFile(path.absolutePath)
        }
    }

    runBlocking {
        deferred.map {
            it.await()
        }
    }
    println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000)
}

suspend fun findTxtFile(path: String) {
    //println("--------------------- $path")
    if (File(path).isDirectory) {
        File(path).listFiles().forEach {
            findTxtFile(it.absolutePath) //===> Exception happen here
        }
    } else if (path.endsWith(".java")) {
        println(path)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you already wrote the code. What is the actual question you have?

Comment: This is single thread, how to make it faster by using coroutines in kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a  `fun findTxtFile(path: String)` to be `suspend`. Remove that modifier and it will work. 
`suspend` modifier lets you use coroutines inside of method, but you don't have any coroutines inside - so it's unnecessary